# how to create AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#

I am new to c#. In my solution, there are lots of projects with AssemblyInfo.cs in Properties. I want to create a new project also with AssemblyInfo.cs in Properties like the existed ones. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180543/what-is-assemblyinfo-cs-used-for

Comment: It should already be one there when you create a new project. If you right click on the project  in the Solution Explorer, and select 'Properties' in the special window that opens, on the 'Application' tab, there is an 'Assembly Information...' button. Click this and it will give you a popup dialog with common fields to enter.

Comment: Note: if AssemblyInfo.cs has somehow been deleted (or not created), clicking the 'Assembly Information...' button and add some text to at least 1 of the fields will generate a brand AssemblyInfo.cs file in Visual Studio in your Solution Explorer. I cannot attest to whether VSCode does that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is AssemblyInfo.cs file needed for .Net Core projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125531/is-assemblyinfo-cs-file-needed-for-net-core-projects)

Comment: If you want to add your own AssemblyInfo.cs, pay special attention to the example that includes the `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>` element.