# .AssemblyInfo.cs file creates a duplicate attribute error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, assemblyinfo

I'm writing a client in c# using VS 2019, which includes a GUI in WPF (this is my first project in WPF). When I ran the project I got errors which say that there are multiple declarations for several attributes -

> Duplicate 'attribute' attribute

I checked the file the error came from, which was an .AssemblyInfo.cs, and saw in the file explorer that several other files which are identical were created.

As I didn't want to change the files at the client, I created a new WPF project to experiment and understand the problem. I ran the program, and it worked. I decided to run it after adding another window, to simulate my client better, and it still worked.

For now, I don't want to continue trying and experimenting because I think that I reached the limit of my experimental project, and I don't want to edit files I don't understand in the main project.

Unfourtantly, I don't know any way this problem is duplicatable on another computer, but I think creating a WPF project would give a good sense of what is going on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125531/is-assemblyinfo-cs-file-needed-for-net-core-projects

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, it hadn't revealed the solution straight away but it did help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I explained that I don't find any way the problem is duplicatable